# OpenVPN fails to connect when switching from Windows XP to Windows 7 - with same ovpn profile

Tags: windows-7, vpn, openvpn, gui

My workplace has a VPN set up, which I used to connect to using OpenVPN on Win XP. Now I'm trying to achieve the same on a Win 7 64bit box.

- I installed the 64bit OpenVPN client (March 2013 release)
- I copied the config file to the appropriate directory (.ovpn file in C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config)
- I started the GUI and chose 'Connect'.

The First thing I noted is that it's not the GUI I remember... I remember a dialog coming up with the round orange circle icon for each configured connection, on a button which you could press for connection. Now the GUI is putty-agent-like.

Anyway, when I try to connect, I get:

```
Sun May 12 09:17:50 2013 OpenVPN 2.3.1 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [IPv6] built on Mar 28 2013
Sun May 12 09:17:50 2013 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Sun May 12 09:17:50 2013 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Sun May 12 09:17:51 2013 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Sun May 12 09:17:51 2013 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]IP.ADDR.GOES.HERE:1194
```

where instead of IP.ADDR.GOES.HERE there's an actual IP address.

After this happens, the connection is seemingly not up.

What's going on?

**Edit:** I no longer have access to the VPN in question, so I currently can't accept or reject answers.

Comment: Your connection doesn't even seem to be reaching the remote server, or you are not getting a reply.

Answer (score 1):

If the Dialogue Box has changed from Rounded edges to a Square edge Window you have probably swapped from the **OpenVPN Access Server Product (Licensed)** to the **OpenVPN Free Open Source Software Product (Free)**.  The OpenVPN Website does not make this distinction particularly clear as they fight over the OpenVPN name.  You Must Consult the Network Administrator at your Workplace for the correct Client Software.

Comment: I'm no longer using that VPN, but that's very good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change the name of the adapter the config file is expecting in the `dev` line to what the OpenVPN adapter actually is, or vice versa.

Clairifying my answer just a bit, you need to look in `ncpa.cpl` - the OpenVPN adapter might be something like "Local Area Connection 2" - you may need to change your `dev` line to `dev "Local Area Connection 2"` - or, rename the adapter with F2 to match what is in the config file, if you can.

I usually name my OpenVPN TAP adapter `openvpn` for simplicity, as you can't count on Windows giving a fixed name to it anyway.

Comment: Well, changing the name did not work. I still get the same errors.